# mysql module in php

Tags: mysql, module, php

I am not seeing mysql as one module when i do `php -m`. I visited various other questions and checked `php.ini` but I don't see this line `extension=php_mysql.dll`

Do i need to add this line? if yes, where it should go. please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unless MySQL's module is compiled directly into PHP (in which case it'd be always available), you have to explicitly state you want the external .dll loaded.

As for where it should go, it depends. PHP has usually has at least 2 main .ini files, one for webserver-embedded operations, and one for command line operations. You'll have to add the line to whichever is applicable for your case. It doesn't hurt to add it to both, unless you want a "stripped down" PHP with as few modules loaded as possible.